# Uploading a file via FTP using an Android smartphone

Tags: java, android, apache, upload, ftp

I'm trying to upload an file via FTP from my Android Smartphone with my own app. I've got a done code, but it isn't working. Instead it throws me Exceptions in Logact. I hope you can help me.

Used Library: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html

My Code:

```
package com.florian.ftpupload;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

import com.florian.ftpupload.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UploadActivity extends Activity{

public static final String TAG = "Contacts";

public String host = "<serverip>";
public String username = "<username>";
public String password = "<password>";
public String database = "test.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);


    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                DatabaseUpload();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    Log.i(TAG, "thread started");


}

protected void DatabaseUpload() throws SocketException, IOException {
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
      ftp.connect(host);
      int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

      if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FTP server refused connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      ftp.login(username, password);
      ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
      ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

      InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(database);
      ftp.storeFile("test.txt", fis);
      fis.close();

      ftp.logout();
      ftp.disconnect();
}
}
```

My LogCat Errors:

```
D/Genymotion(   56): Received Ping
I/ActivityManager(  366): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=    [android.
intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000   cmp=com.florian.ftpupload/.UploadActivi
ty} from pid 586
D/dalvikvm(  366): GC_CONCURRENT freed 805K, 16% free 7450K/8816K, paused     1ms+2m
s, total 20ms
I/ActivityManager(  366): Start proc com.florian.ftpupload for activity     com.flor
ian.ftpupload/.UploadActivity: pid=1421 uid=10051 gids={50051, 1028}
I/qtaguid (  366): Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10051) res=-1 errno=1
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(  366): setKernelCountSet(10051, 1) failed   with
errno -1
E/dalvikvm( 1421): Could not find class     'org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient',
referenced from method com.florian.ftpupload.UploadActivity.DatabaseUpload
W/dalvikvm( 1421): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1557   (Lorg/apache/commons
/net/ftp/FTPClient;) in Lcom/florian/ftpupload/UploadActivity;
D/dalvikvm( 1421): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
D/dalvikvm( 1421): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2a97 at 0x02 in     Lcom/flor
ian/ftpupload/UploadActivity;.DatabaseUpload
I/Contacts( 1421): thread started
W/dalvikvm( 1421): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x
a614c908)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1421): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-122
E/AndroidRuntime( 1421): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org.apache.commons.net.
ftp.FTPClient
E/AndroidRuntime( 1421):        at     com.florian.ftpupload.UploadActivity.Database
Upload(UploadActivity.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1421):        at   com.florian.ftpupload.UploadActivity$1.run(Up
loadActivity.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1421):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
W/ActivityManager(  366):   Force finishing activity  com.florian.ftpupload/.Uplo
adActivity
D/libEGL  ( 1421): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
D/        ( 1421): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established   0xb7b1a
f98, tid 1421
D/libEGL  ( 1421): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
D/libEGL  ( 1421): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
I/ActivityManager(  366): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=    [android.
intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000     cmp=com.florian.ftpupload/.UploadActivi
ty} from pid 586
W/EGL_genymotion( 1421): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
D/OpenGLRenderer( 1421): Enabling debug mode 0
I/Contacts( 1421): thread started
W/dalvikvm( 1421): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x
a614c908)
I/Process ( 1421): Sending signal. PID: 1421 SIG: 9
I/qtaguid (  366): Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10051) res=-1 errno=1
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(  366): setKernelCountSet(10051, 0) failed   with
errno -1
I/ActivityManager(  366): Process com.florian.ftpupload (pid 1421) has died.
I/WindowState(  366): WIN DEATH: Window{533f06e4 u0     com.florian.ftpupload/com.fl
orian.ftpupload.UploadActivity}
W/ActivityManager(  366): Force removing ActivityRecord{5348c488 u0     com.florian.
ftpupload/.UploadActivity}: app died, no saved state
I/WindowState(  366): WIN DEATH: Window{5343b134 u0     com.florian.ftpupload/com.fl
orian.ftpupload.UploadActivity}
W/EGL_genymotion(  586): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/InputMethodManagerService(  366): Window already focused, ignoring focus   gain
of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@53330148   attribute=n
ull, token = android.os.BinderProxy@533c6a54
D/Genymotion(   56): Received Ping
```

I hope you understand my problem ;)

~Florian

Comment: You have a `NoClassDefFoundError` on that `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` class. Are you sure you're importing the library properly in your project?

Comment: I thought I've done it right. @Ace_McIntosh could you tell me how to import correctly?

Comment: Are you using Gradle? In that case, you should have this dependency in your build.gradle application file `compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.4'`. See the Maven repository that this is the package you need to import the classes in the `org.apache.commons.net.ftp` package: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/3.4. Alternatively, you can add the library's .jar file into your project.

Comment: The .jar file is added in Referenced Libraries and in the libs folder. @Ace_McIntosh

Comment: If the library is imported, then I guess something went wrong during the build process (probably something with the generated .dex file – the package is not seemingly present during runtime), may be something wrong in the build configuration. For starters (you may have already tried that, if it didn't help, it's probably something in the configuration), you can try Build - Clean Project (assuming you're using Android Studio) or `gradle clean` to see if it's just a one-off error.

Comment: I've fixed the problem. I forgot to set a cross the exportinterface.